# Display two dates in one gridview column

Tags: gridview

I'm using the following in my grid view to display two dates in a single column.
How can I change this so the date format will be like dd MMM yyyy without the time?

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Range">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# string.Format("{0} {1}", Eval("From_Date ") ,Eval("To_Date"))%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a matter of adding `:dd MMM yyyy` after 0, resp 1

Like:

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Date Range">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <%# string.Format("{0:dd MMM yyyy} {1:dd MMM yyyy}", Eval("From_Date") ,Eval("To_Date"))%>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: Thanks Robert - that works perfectly.

Any Idea how I might be able to hide the second date when it is the same as the first date? I'm posting a new question about this anyway, but maybe you know how...

Comment: I have given it a shot! not sure it is corret though as I can't compile it right now